# How do types work in Pokemon Quest?

Tags: pokemon-quest

We know that [your team gains bonus Team Strength when including Pokemon of specific type whilst exploring areas weak to that type](https://www.pokemon.com/us/strategy/top-tips-to-start-your-pokemon-quest/).

However, each Pokemon has moves with different types too (e.g Growlithe has a normal type and fire type move). What's the mechanics behind move types?

Answer (score 2):

Move types works as the classic games, they respect the [type chart](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Type#Type_chart) excluding 0x which appears to be *not very effective* instead of *no effect*.

Also if the move is the same type as the Pokemon that uses it, the move receives a bonus as confirmed by the in-game tips. A sort of STAB (Same Type Attack Bonus), which in the classic games is a 50% bonus.